# Linear model coefficients over time

Tags: time-series, anova, multiple-regression, ordinal-data, friedman-test

I have one scale dependent variable $Y$ and 15 ordinal independent $X_1, X_2, ..., X_{15}$, measured three times in three consecutive years. My purpose is to measure the extend that $Y$ correlates with the ordinal variables taking into account time variation.

A repeated measures ANOVA reveals that Y does not have a significant change over time, while Friedman's test verifies that all 15 ordinal variables increases in time. Further, in each consecutive year Y a linear model verifies that Y is not significantly related to the $X_i$'s (assuming that the $X_i$'s are hiding a scale variable).

So the question is:

Are the above results sufficient to declare that Y is independent to $X_i$'s *taking into account time factor* or there is another more appropriate way (probably from time series theory that will ensure that coefficients of the linear model are *stable* over time)

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: @Epalminondas PL. specify variables dep. as well as X variables. Your Y variable is scaled and independent variables are ordinal(explain). ANOVA MAY NOT BE JUSTIFIED

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In fact the above description is only a possible approach and not my final decision. My question is on the way that a prediction model can be applied taking into account the time factor in order to prove my assumption that Y is statistically independent from the $X_i$.

Comment: Your results are not sufficient to conclude that Y is indepent of X variables. Pool your data and go for multiple regression.

Comment: @ subhash c. davar how could I apply multiple regression and take into account the three distinct measurements for all variables?

Comment: @@Epaminondas How many subjects are there? It seems that you have three mrasurements (Annual) for each subject.Further data may be given in tabular format.

Comment: I have 120 subjects and for each variable I have 3 measurements. I am not sure that multiple regression is the appropriate method, since it seems that time factor can not be represented in such a linear model.

Comment: It is a case of time-series cross-section data

Comment: contd. However you must reduce number of X variables to obtain valid regression coefficients. may collasce the number by Exploratory factor analysis or with rationality.

Comment: Could you please provide further clarification at your comments? What is the exact statistical procedure you suggest?

Comment: 15 explanatory variables are too many for a multiple regression. Hence reduce the number of such variables.There are number of ways. For example, some of similar variables may be deleted or merged to avoid multiple interacyions among the variables.

Comment: Could you please clarify how time factor will be inserted in a regression model?